# Why is FB.Event.subscribe firing?

Tags: facebook

What causes the FB.Event.subscribe event to fire?

I know clicking an fb:login-button element can trigger it but the FB.Event.subscribe event is firing anytime a Facebook session is created.

Do other FBML elements automatically trigger this event when a Facebook session is present or does this event trigger regardless of regardless of any FBML elements present?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FB.Event.subscribe` by itself is not an event, it's just like the addListener where it hook an event to a function. You need to check your code to see what events you are using:

- auth.login -- fired when the user logs in
- auth.logout -- fired when the user logs out
- auth.sessionChange -- fired when the session changes
- auth.statusChange -- fired when the status changes
- xfbml.render -- fired when a call to FB.XFBML.parse() completes
- edge.create -- fired when the user likes something (fb:like)
- edge.remove -- fired when the user unlikes something (fb:like)
- comments.create -- fired when the user adds a comment (fb:comments)
- comments.remove -- fired when the user removes a comment (fb:comments)
- fb.log -- fired on log message

I suppose you have the `auth.sessionChange` **event** used.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue, but the solution I found was:

1. In `FB.init`, set the parameter **status** to **false** (in almost all samples I saw it comes as true by default)
2. Trigger the login events using the **auth.statusChange**

So you'll end with something like it:

```
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
            appId: 'YOUR-APPID',
            channelUrl: '//www.YOUR-DOMAIN.com/channel.html',
            status: false,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe("auth.statusChange", function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse)
            {
                if (FBLoginCallback) FBLoginCallback();
            }
        });
    };

    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    } (document));
</script>
```

Notice that I made a callback function named **FBLoginCallback()**, so I can use this code in a MasterPage, and define the callback handling function in separated pages, each with its specific needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can only know what triggers each event by looking at the Facebook docs or by looking through the JS SDK source code. Here are links for both of those:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/#events
- https://github.com/fashy/fbtracking/blob/master/js-sdk/all.beautified.js

In the JS source, look for calls to **FB.Event.fire( ... )**. You may have to do some more analysis to figure out the exact conditions, especially since my version of the JS is from a minified version of the SDK. Facebook does not release their actual source at this time so we have to make do with de-minifying the final SDK.