# FB.Event.subscribe Event is unstable?

Tags: javascript, facebook, events, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using Facebook Javascript SDK.

Using FB.Event.subscribe is unstable because sometimes it does not catch

though some events are triggered.

Is there a way to catch those events without missing them?

In my case,

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', commentUp);
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.remove', commentDown);
```

comment events are not firing rarely.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125412/why-is-fb-event-subscribe-firing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has solved!

My problem was that I have put

fbAsyncInit function and FB.Event.Subscribe inside of $(document).ready(function() });

It is solved since I have put those Very front of my javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

FB.Event.Subscribe works flawlessly for me.
Use firebug and see to it that there are no JS errors when comment is clicked ..